# How do I get my Django query to only return an average and another column?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, aggregate, average

I'm using Django and Python 3.7.  I have these models ...

```
class Article(models.Model):
    website = models.ForeignKey(Website, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='articlesite')
    title = models.TextField(default='', null=False)
    path = models.TextField(default='', null=False)
    url = models.TextField(default='', null=False)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, default=datetime.now)


class ArticleStat(models.Model):
    objects = ArticleStatManager()
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='articlestats')
    elapsed_time_in_seconds = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=False)
    hits = models.FloatField(default=0, null=False)
```

I want to write a Django query that returns two columns of data -- an elapsed_time_in_seconds (from the ArticleStat model above) and an average of the hits for this particular interval.  There are a couple of other constraints in the mix.  I have no idea how to do this.  I tried the below

```
qset = ArticleStat.objects.annotate(avg_score=Avg(F("hits")),
                                    hour=(Func(
                                            Func(
                                                F("article__created_on"), function='HOUR FROM'),
                                            function='EXTRACT'))).filter(
    article__website=website,
    hour=hour)
```

but this results in the error, "TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object".  I'm confused about how to specify the "GROUP BY" part of my SQL statement, and then I'm confused about how to return the two columns of data I want, since I think the above only returns ArticleStat objects, which wouldn't include my average in there.

Comment: The objects do include the average if you have annotated them. If you don't need objects but just two fields, use [values()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#values).

Comment: Oh ok I'm fine to have the object if it also includes the new field I want.  However, why am I getting the "TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object" error in the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set an output field on the `hour` annotation otherwise Django doesn't know you've converted the original date type (`created_on`) into a number type (`hour`), and expects to be passed a date string (or a date object, which it confusingly doesn't say however). If you pass a date as `hour` to `filter()`, you'll see that the `TypeError` goes away (but you'll get a `ProgrammingError` from the database).

So given that you extract the hour as an integer, how about using an `IntegerField`:

```
from django.db.models import IntegerField

qset = ArticleStat.objects.annotate(
    avg_score=Avg(F("hits")),
    hour=(Func(
            Func(F("article__created_on"), function='HOUR FROM'),
            function='EXTRACT',
            output_field=IntegerField()
    ))
)
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  So per your comment, to force a group by expression with only "elapsed_time_in_seconds", I added values('elapsed_time_in_seconds'), but even so, the GROUP BY sql generated includes both taht and 'EXTRACT(HOUR FROM("article"."created_on"'.  How do I force the GROUP BY to only include the one column?

Comment: Separate the annotations as they have different purposes. One is for filtering, the other for aggregating. Annotate `hour` first, then filter on `hour`, then do a `values` with only the value(s) you want to group by, then annotate with the desired aggregation(s). If it doesn't work, post the updated query in the question.